# Passing arbitrary slices in Go

Tags: pointers, go, slice

I'm writing a function that retrieves arbitrary data from a database, and returns a slice of structs with the results. The data structure is defined by the user in an ItemFactory. The user then implements methods on the factory, that create empty structs:

```
func (t Example) GenerateEmptyItem() interface{} {
    return &Example{}
}
```

I am trying to do the same for slices of `Example`. I need to be able to use whatever is returned, to call functions such as `len()`, while at the same time, keeping it generic as to allow it to be returned by "generic" functions.

I can't simply have something like this, as the underlying data allocation for a slice of interfaces is different from a slice of Examples:

```
func (t Country) GenerateEmptyItems() []interface{} {
    return []Country{} //Error
}
```

Is it possible to use a pointer to a slice, such as `&[]Example{}` and pass it as an `interface{}`, and then still be able to use it as a slice? Or am I going about this wrong?.Remember, I don't know the type of the data at compile-time, so I can't simply cast.

I appreciate any help. Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: A pointer doesn't change anything, it's just a pointer. If you need to operate on data without knowing the type, you need to use reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't quite do this directly.

You can use [reflection](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/), however this isn't a great solution. The normal way is to have an interface type defined that lets you interact with all the data in the same way. A good example of this is the [sort](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) package.

Comment: Might just have to use reflection, as I don't want the user to have to define too much.

If `items` is a pointer to a slice of interfaces, I can get the underlying slice with `i := reflect.ValueOf(items).Elem().Interface()`. However, `i` is still an interface at compile time. Do you know how I can have that interpreted as a slice? Would I just have to do a reflect `MakeSlice()` and copy the elements over?

Comment: I might be a bit confused by what you are asking. You can use reflect to inspect `i` and fetch each element via https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Index